# How to update subsite(variance) title in current and global navigation programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have created variance with English and German and its reference URL is added in current and global navigation. I want to update title of variance site in current and global navigation. How to do that?

```
SPNavigationNodeCollection quickLaunchNav1 = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
                        PortalSiteMapProvider sitemapprovider = (PortalSiteMapProvider)SiteMap.Providers["CurrentNavSiteMapProvider"];
                        SiteMapNode rootNode = sitemapprovider.CurrentNode;


                        if (rootNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (SiteMapNode childNode in rootNode.ChildNodes)
                            {
                                if (childNode.Title.Equals("de-de"))
                                {
                                    childNode.Title = "Test";

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

But in child node there is not any property of update. How to update title of child node?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to alter the sitemap provider node, just change the QuickLaunch node like this:

```
SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
foreach (SPNavigationNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.Title.Equals("de-de"))
    {
        node.Title = "Test";
        node.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But en-us and de-de site-node is not available in nodes collection.Don't know why it was not coming on loop.